# Mongodb query excludes a field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this problem, my query looks like this:

```
  public findCitys(city: string) {
    return City.find(
      {
        country: 'AT',
        $text: {
          $search: city,
        },
      },
      {
        score: {
          $meta: 'textScore',
        },
      }
    )
      .sort({
        score: {
          $meta: 'textScore',
        },
      })
      .limit(5)
  }
```

And my model looks like this:

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: 'text',
  },
  location: {
    type: String,
    coordinates: [Number],
  },
})
```

When i use the query above i get the result without the `location` field. Why is that?

I need to note here that `location` has an 2dsphere index on it

Here an example output:

```
[                                                                                                                                                           
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("619217adf9f5ad76d27d387f"),
    name: 'Vienna',
    country: 'AT',
    score: 1.1
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the problem. It was in my schema.
`type` is an reserved keyword but i need it as an object key

```
const citySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  country: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: 'text',
  },
  location: {
    type: {
       type: String
    },
    coordinates: [Number],
  },
})
```

Now it works